# tblastn search using GI instead of fasta

Tags: blast

I have to perform a tblastn for some gi's. I've been testing my script with a fasta file, and it worked perfectly, but now, when I've tried with a GI number, it crashed.

```
tblastn -query 351738029 db /home/databases/nt/nt -out $output -show_gis
```

I've tried with just the number, with gi|351738029 but I fail to see where the problem is.

**EDIT** : I've also tried this

```
tblastn -query gi|351738029|gb|AEQ61064.1| db /home/databases/nt/nt -out $output -show_gis
```

But the "|" are interpreted as pipes. Also tried writing the whole GI between "", but useless.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you cannot simply use as an argument the gi directly, it has to be inside of a file. The bright side is that you can use a file with several gi's, and it will query all of them.